# Python - Shutil.copy vs fnmatch vs regular expression

Tags: python, regex, shutil

I have a directory with multiple files beginning with `integers`. I am attempting to copy some of them to another directory based on a `string` pattern within the file name. I can successfully copy multiple files starting with integers (which I commented out), but am having trouble filtering based on the string pattern. I'm using `shutil.copy`, but am having trouble in determining whether to use `regex` or `fnmatch`.

My code below filters correctly, but still copies all files, not files with the specific string `'TEST_Payroll'`. Any help to do this would be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
import re
import os
import fnmatch
import shutil

src_files = os.listdir('C:/Users/acars/Desktop/a')
regex_txt = 'TEST_Payroll'
source = 'C:/Users/acars/Desktop/a' 
dest1 = 'C:/Users/acars/Desktop/b'

for file_name in src_files: 
#if not file_name.startswith(('0','1','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9',)):
if fnmatch.filter(file_name, 'TEST_Payroll'):
    continue
src = os.path.join(source, file_name)
dst = os.path.join(dest1, file_name)  
shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

Comment: If you only want to copy files with `'TEST_Payroll'`, your conditional should be `if not fnmatch.filter(file_name, 'TEST_Payroll'): continue`

Comment: That copies 0 files over now. Not sure if it's worth mentioning, but this string is in the middle of the file name. All file names in the directory start with integers, so my commented out method did not work above. Thanks for the response!

Comment: You can just do `if 'TEST_Payroll' not in file_name`

Comment: Looks good, thanks! I need to get better with 'not in'... it's a little counter intuitive. The syntax makes it sound as if this would select the files I am not trying to select. This is why I'm still learning! Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

How about using,

```
if re.search(r'TEST_Payroll',file_name):
    #do something with file
else:
    #else do nothing
```